# GravityForms Pre-Populate Field Value based on ACF Post Type Field - Dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I have a custom post type, and am using Elementor, PAFE, and ACF Pro, and Gravity Forms. For visually reasons I used PAFE/Elementor and at the end of my form process I am creating a Custom Post Type "Contract" and then once the contract is created it redirects to a page with a gravity form on it (hiding the ACF values). I want the Custom Field Values associated with the contract to shared with gravity forms but I am not successfully mapping it..

I have tried this but no luck. I am not sure which GravityForms filter I need to load in custom values.

Referencing: 
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value', 'populate_fields');


function populate_fields( $value, $field, $name ) {

    $values = array(
        'pc'   => get_field('pc',),
        'dc'   => get_field('dc'),
        'tt'   => get_field('tt'),
        'rd'   => get_field('rd'),
        'vl'   => get_field('vl'),
        'on'   => get_field('on'),
        'fn'   => get_field('fn'),
        'ln'   => get_field('ln'),
        'cp'   => get_field('cp'),
        'ph'   => get_field('ph'),
        'e'   => get_field('e'),
        'apd'   => get_field('apd'),
        'tariff'   => get_field('tariff'),
        'c2c'   => get_field('c2c'),
        'tsc'   => get_field('tsc'),
        'awc'   => get_field('awc'),
        'pp_address'   => get_field('pp_address'),
        'pp_fn'   => get_field('pp_fn'),
        'pp_ln'   => get_field('pp_ln'),
        'pp_biz'   => get_field('pp_biz'),
        'pp_ph'   => get_field('pp_ph'),
        'pp_notes'   => get_field('pp_notes'),
        'do_address'   => get_field('do_address'),
        'do_fn'   => get_field('do_fn'),
        'do_ln'   => get_field('do_ln'),
        'do_biz'   => get_field('do_biz'),
        'do_notes'   => get_field('do_notes')
    );

    return isset( $values[ $name ] ) ? $values[ $name ] : $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check your ACF fields and gravity form key are valid or not. You can also pass the id while getting data from the get_field() like as below:

This example shows a variety of $post_id values to get a value from a post, user, term, and option.

```
$post_id = false; // current post
$post_id = 1; // post ID = 1
$post_id = "user_2"; // user ID = 2
$post_id = "category_3"; // category term ID = 3
$post_id = "event_4"; // event (custom taxonomy) term ID = 4
$post_id = "option"; // options page
$post_id = "options"; // same as above

$value = get_field( 'my_field', $post_id );
```

I hope it would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that did the trick, I was able to get it to work like this, but I didn't assign variable to save some time writing code probably not the best practice in terms of performance but it works.
:

```
function populate_fields( $value, $field, $name ) {                                  

    //to use current post                                                                             
    $post_id = false;                                                                                                      

    $values = array(                                                                 
        'do_notes'   => get_field( 'do_notes', $post_id ),                                                    
    );                                                                               

    return isset( $values[ $name ] ) ? $values[ $name ] : $value;                    
}
```